# Best way to display files from directory and from FTP server using Swing components

Tags: java, swing, directory, jtable

I am looking for best way to display files. Should I use `JTable` or is there another way of displaying files?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try with a `JTree`.

See [JTree basic tutorial and examples](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/jtree-basic-tutorial-and-examples) for more details.

Comment: Well I would prefer so my list looks more like this:
http://www.chip.de/ii/1/0/1/0/3/2/8/9/69a50ba0718f9416.jpg
I am trying to write a ftp client.

Comment: See the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784) for both tree & tabular based options. Personally I think 'both combined' is both the most visually pleasing & use to the end user.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am starting writing the code. After I finish i will show you guys my final product :)